# How can I use hyper-V in windows 7 on a Macbook pro using Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, windows

How can I use hyper-V in windows 7 on a Macbook pro using Bootcamp ?

When I try to connect to server localhost there is an Error LIKE THIS :

"Hyper-V has not been installed on computer localhost"

I have searched internet but couldn't find anything useful to solve my problem

I m on macbook pro with retina

any idea ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hyper-V` isn't available for Windows 7. You have to install at least Windows 8 Pro/Enterprise or Windows Server 2008/2012. [(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#System_requirements)

You might [install](http://blogs.technet.com/b/schadinio/archive/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7.aspx) `Hyper-V Manager` (probably you did already) though. This application allows to manage `Hyper-V` hypervisors installed on other computers meeting the above mentioned Operating System requirements.